# To find the number of matrices

Tags: matrices

Is  there  any  formula  to  find  the  number  of  all  possible   matrices  of  order  n × n  with  each  entry  0  or  1 ?

Comment: Pick whether $a_{1,1}$ is zero or one (*two options*).  Pick whether $a_{1,2}$ is zero or one (*two options*)... repeat for each of the entries in the matrix.  You had a total of $n^2$ such entries to decide their value with two options for each.  Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and conclude.

Comment: Thank u for helping☺

Comment: more interesting (and complicated) would have been if you were asking for the number of **invertible** square binary matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 2 choices for $n^2$ entries thus for the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

$$\overbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot 2}^{\color{red}{n^2 \,times}}=2^{n^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

I'd say $2^{n^2}$ for you have 2 choices for each of the $n^2$ entries